# Create column that checks if the total exceeds another column...SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2016

I have a table with these columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Site]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WellId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalOil] [int] NOT NULL,

)
```

I'm creating another table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reserves]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WellId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalOil] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalGas] [int] NOT NULL,
    ....
)
```

and I want one of the columns to have a constraint that the total cannot exceed the `TotalOil` of my `Site` table.

I tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reserves]  
    ADD CHECK (TotalOil <= [dbo].Site.[TotalOil])
```

This throws an error in SSMS:

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.Site.TotalOil" could not be bound.

How do I add a constraint that makes sure the `TotalOil` column in my `Reserves` table not exceed the `TotalOil` column value in my `Site` table? Thank you

Comment: Please provide both tables sample data. It is unclear how to handle it when both tables have multiple rows.

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: You have two choices.  A user-defined function or a trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a function that returns the TotalOil from the Site table and reference that in the check constraint.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TotalOil(@SiteId INT) RETURNS INT 
AS BEGIN 
RETURN (
 SELECT 
  TotalOil
 FROM dbo.Site
 WHERE SiteId = @SiteId)
END
```

Then you can reference this in the check constraint on the Reserve table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Reserves ADD CHECK ( TotalOil <= dbo.TotalOil(SiteId))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a user-defined function or a trigger.

```
create function usp_get_totaloil (
    @siteId int
) returns int as
begin
    declare @TotalOil int;

    select @TotalOil = s.TotalOil
    from [dbo].Site s
    where s.SiteId = @siteId;

    return @TotalOil;
end;
```

Then the `check` constraint looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reserves] ADD CHECK ( TotalOil <= dbo.usp_get_totaloil(site) );
```